# cannot print out specific data with xpath and webdriver

Tags: python, xpath, webdriver

cannot print out specific data with xpath and webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://datatables.net/")
print driver.findtext('.//*[@id="example"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]')
```

Expected Result:

```
Airi Satou
```

Comment: Do not update your question with the code attempts suggested in answers. Leave your original code

Comment: dear, noted with thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one to get desired output:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

print(wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//table[@id="example"]//td'))).text)
```

Comment: dear, "" selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .//*[@id="example"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1] ""

Comment: sorry, dear , selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //table[@id="example"]//td

Comment: dear, "" selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: """

Comment: Are you sure that this "https://datatables.net/" is the page you're navigating to?